# Study corruption vs economic growth

Tags: reference-request

I am trying to study how corruption affects the economic growth of a country. I am not trying to look at a global scale. So, I am trying to find some literature on that front. However, some I found are mostly done on a global scale or for multiple countries. Do you know authors who have done similar research? I want to see how such research is done so I can follow and most likely give my twist when I am ready.